# Rails PostgreSQL socket path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Suppose that I have a Postgres cluster running, with its Unix domain socket located under /some/custom/path

How do I set up my database.yml so that the Rails app can connect to the cluster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the postgres docs:

> host: Name of host to connect to. If this begins with a slash, it specifies Unix-domain communication rather than TCP/IP communication; the value is the name of the directory in which the socket file is stored.

The ActiveRecord adapter just passes through the host parameter so it's as simple as just putting this line in your `database.yml`:

```
host: /path/to/socket/file
```

Comment: @MrMobster It's actually really unclear in the ActiveRecord docs **and** in the docs for the PG gem that combined they provide little more than a thin Ruby wrapper around libpq. I banged my head against this exact issue for a couple of hours once!